# String rewrite system for algebraic knots/links?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, symbolic-dynamics, formal-languages

$\newcommand\over{\vert}\newcommand\rot[1]{\mathopen<#1\mathclose>}$By its definition, an algebraic tangle, and by extension, its closure (knot or link) can be written as a string (of concatenated operations). For example, let $\over$ denote an overcrossing, $\rot x$ (bracketing) the rotation of $x$ by $90°$ (for simplicity I assume all mutants are equal) and $xy$ (concatenation) addition (this forms a complete set of operations to generate all algebraic tangles). Then, say, $\over\rot{\over\over\over\rot{\rot{\rot\over}}}$ is a valid tangle, and it can be simplified since $\forall_{xyz}$ $y\rot{\rot x}z=yxz$, $x\over\rot\over y=xy$ and $y\over\rot{\over x}z=y\rot{\rot x\rot\over}z$ (a longer string, but fewer crossings!). Since the operations are local, the rules are context-free.

The question is obvious: Is there a string rewriting system which can decide algorithmically if two tangles are equal, preferably in $O(L)$ ($L$ string length) time? (You can use other fundamental operations — in particular, it would be nice to have a binary string which can be easily decoded.)

Note: I experimented a bit and only needed two more complicated rules (which are still easy applications of Reidemeister moves) to get at least all tangles with $6$ crossings enumerated correctly (in this system the tangle corresponding to the Borromean rings can only be expressed with $7$ crossings instead of $5$, so I don't count these). But $6$ is far too small...

Comment: I edited to make the `<>` behave as brackets rather than as relations, using `\mathopen<` and `\mathclose>` instead (compare $a<x>b$ `a<x>b` to $a\mathopen<x\mathclose>b$ `a\mathopen<x\mathclose>b`), but still repeated rotations look a bit unfortunate.  Are you opposed to $\langle x\rangle$ `\langle x\rangle`, which nests better (compare $\mathopen<\mathopen<x\mathclose>\mathclose>$ `\mathopen<\mathopen<x\mathclose>\mathclose>` to $\langle\langle x\rangle\rangle$ `\langle\langle x\rangle\rangle`)?

Comment: Isn't this directly equivalent to asking for a simplification algorithm, in the language of diagrams and Reidemeister moves, since they are local as well.   Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @LSpice: Doesn't matter, could have used () either :-)

Comment: @RyanBudney: Almost! I know very well that a simplification algorithm for arbitrary knots is a very hairy thing, needing sometimes expansions (more crossings) and so on. But I'm fairly sure that when you limit to algebraic tangles, things get much simpler. For example, you can't describe a R3 move in this system at all (or so I think), but you don't have to (or so I think), since certain combinations of Reidemeister moves directly describable as tangle operations might suffice. I simply don't know, and that's why I asked.

Comment: Algebraic tangles, thought of as $\pi$-orbifolds, have a JSJ decomposition with vertices given by Seifert orbifolds fibering over a planar surface with mirror string boundary, and decomposing along Conway spheres in which the Seifert fiberings on either side don't match. I think that there is a nice description for such spaces, e.g. Conway developed a notation for 2-dimensional orbifolds, and gluing the tori corresponds to choosing the slopes of the fibers in a torus, which amounts to continued fractions. So there might be a nice algorithm to get things in a canonical form.

Comment: You might have a look at Bonahon & Siebenmann's unpublished book on this topic. https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/1191/docs/Preprints/BonSieb.pdf

Comment: @IanAgol: THX, immediatedly hamstered :-) Good (or bad) is the chance that I don't understand anything after the first "Let", but so there. BTW&AFAIK, continued fractions refer to rational, but not arborescent.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann Maybe have a look at the section on the “plumbing calculus”, it might describe some of the sorts of transformations you would need for string rewriting.